A test for exactness of second order ODEs $N(x,y,y')y''+M(x,y,y')=0$
The ODE
\begin{align}
N(x,y)p+M(x,y)=0;\quad [p=y'_x]
\end{align}
can be tested for exactness by checking if $N_x=M_y$. This test is found by assuming a first integral of the form $U(x,y)=C$ with derivative $U_yp+U_x=0$. If $U$ is a nice function then $U_{yx}=U_{xy}$, and if $U$ is indeed a first integral it must be that $N_x=M_y$.
Consider now the second order ODE
\begin{align}
N(x,y,p)p'_x+M(x,y,p)=0.
\end{align}
To see if this equation is exact we assume a first integral of the form $U(x,y,p)=C$ with derivative $U_{p}p'+U_yp+U_x=0$. If $U$ is indeed a first integral we are left with the conditions
\begin{align}\tag{1}
U_{p}=N,\quad U_yp+U_x=M.
\end{align}
If I take two partial derivatives w.r.t $p$ to eliminate $U$ I find the equation
\begin{align}\tag{2}\label{2}
pN_{yp}+2N_y+N_{xp}=M_{pp}.
\end{align}
It seems to me, though, that this equation is necessary but not sufficient for arbitrary $N$ and $M$. Consider the ODE $p'_x+f(x,y)p+g(x,y)=0$, which is obviously exact only if $f_x=g_y$ but satisfies equation (2). Is there a correct way to eliminate $U$ in equations (1)? Or perhaps equation (2) works if we add some restrictions on $N$ and $M$? I imagine taking several derivatives of equation (1) is to blame for this.
